# How to add text to a Word document with Google Docs API?

Tags: javascript, google-docs-api

I'm trying to create a Word document that contains text and images but I can't even make the text appear, I always have a blank document and it doesn't hurt my code.

If someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, I would appreciate it.

```js
gapi.client.docs.documents.create({
  resource: {
    title: "probando api de google docs",
    body: {
      content: [{
        paragraph: {
          elements: [{
            textRun: {
              content: "hi \n",
            },
          }, ],
        },
      }, ],
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Method: documents.create**](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create)

- **creates a blank document** using the title given in the request. Other fields in the request, including any provided content, are **ignored**.

---

If you want to insert a text in your newly created document, you can do the following:

**1. Get the document id of the newly created document. Your create request should return a [REST Resource:document](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#Document) where you can obtain the document id**

Sample Response Body:

```
{
  "title": "Test1",
  "body": {
    "content": [
      {
        "endIndex": 1,
        "sectionBreak": {
          "sectionStyle": {
            "columnSeparatorStyle": "NONE",
            "contentDirection": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
            "sectionType": "CONTINUOUS"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "startIndex": 1,
        "endIndex": 2,
        "paragraph": {
          "elements": [
            {
              "startIndex": 1,
              "endIndex": 2,
              "textRun": {
                "content": "\n",
                "textStyle": {}
              }
            }
          ],
          "paragraphStyle": {
            "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
            "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },

....


  "revisionId": "xxxxxxxxxsamplerevisionid",
  "suggestionsViewMode": "SUGGESTIONS_INLINE",
  "documentId": "xxxxxxxxxsampledocumentid"
}
```

**2. Use [documents.batchUpdate method](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) to insert your text in the document using your document id.**

Sample Request Body:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertText": {
        "location": {
          "index": 1
        },
        "text": "Hello World"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- In this example, I used [InsertTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttextrequest) to insert a text inside the document at a specific location that I want (which is in index 1)

Output:

[image]

**Additional Notes:**
To learn more about the internal structure of a Google Docs document: the elements that make up a document and the relationship between these elements, indexing and positioning.
Refer to this link: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/concepts/structure

To learn more about request methods and responses.
Refer to this link: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/concepts/request-response

For complete REST Resources, refer here: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest